# How to predict an outcome with missing variable?

Tags: regression, prediction, missing-data

Suppose I have two datasets:
One is the training dataset, which has dependent variable $Y$ and independent variables $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$;

Now I have another dataset, which only contains $X_1$ and $X_2$, note that neither $X_3$ nor $Y$ are observed. 
My question is: can we still predict $Y$ from the second dataset, using the regression results from dataset one?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. The model contains the value for X3 and if your newdata does not contain this value it will throw an error.

See following example. I set mtcars in a dataframe, remove the Y column and one of the X columns (cyl). Create a simple lm model based on mtcars and predict on df.

```
df <- mtcars
df$mpg <- NULL # remove Y
    df$cyl <- NULL # remove one X value


lm_model <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
predict(lm_model, df)
```

> ```
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'cyl' not found
> ```

What you could do is impute the missing column to your newdata with the value 0, mean, median or use an imputation function. But then you should realize that your model predictions will be off.

**Edit based on comment:**

Off course, you can skip the X3 column and just regress on X1 and X3. Imputing the value is always a decision based on experience. Median in case of outliers, mean if the data is normally distributed, or imputing if you can deduce the value of X3 based on values of X1 and X2. For example, you could look into the package mice and it's vignette. There are more packages for imputing missing data, but it some of it depends on why the data is missing in the first place. There is a whole body of work on how to deal with missing data.

Here is a [link to chapter 25](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf) of Andrew Gelman's book Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models dealing with missing data.

and [here](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/Software.html) is a link to a list of software package dealing with missing data. The author of mice also wrote an article on this package in the journal of statistical software which you can find [here](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/publications/MICE%20in%20R%20-%20Draft.pdf)

Comment: That is exactly what I experienced. For the missing variable is there any guideline which value I should use? Another idea I have in mind is that since I only have X1 X2, can I just regress Y on X1 X2 only in the training data and then use the results to predict Y from the second dataset? Thanks!

Comment: Note that regressing on only the available data is synonymous to imputing a value of zero for missing data if the variable is continuous, and imputing the "reference level" if the variable is categorical

Comment: Two comments to this answer. (1) Without assuming or handling these missing data some way it is indeed not possible to use this prediction model. But (as alluded to in the answer, but in contradiction with the first sentence), there are assumptions to be made/techniques applied, making using the prediction model possible. 1/2

Comment: (2) I'd argue against saying imputing values is a decision based on experience. Exactly the author of the mice package referred to has worked on multiple real-life data and simulation studies showing that complete case analysis, single imputation (based on median or mean imputation) or missing indicator methods are all seriously biased (and that multiple imputation performs quite well). I will admit, properly performing imputation is something where experience with the technique does come in handy, as it is not always straightforward and some aspects are not yet that well defined. 2/2

Answer (score 1):

The prediction model alone cannot obtain predictions when predictors are missing: more must be done.

There are two basic approaches, both require access to a set of complete data for the $X$ variables. The first approach is to marginalize the prediction model to obtain a *second* prediction model based only on $X_1$ and $X_2$. The other approach is to set up a chain of prediction equations so that you can predict $X_3$ and then predict $Y$ from the complete data.

Both approaches achieve the same purpose and have the same limitations. The number of assumptions grows exponentially with either approach, specifically regarding the consistency of the now three datasets.